# Knockout JS foreach data-binding and nesting element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list that I'd like to produce a link containing an icon and text:

```
<li><a><img src="icon.png" /> name</a></li>
```

So ideally the setup would look like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: list">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="text: name, click: openNavItem"><img data-bind="attr: { src: icon }" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then I'm passing:

```
list.push({ name: "name", icon: "theicon.png" });
```

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6CUq/)

This doesn't work because the 'a data-bind="text: name, ..."' overwrites the image.

Does that make sense? Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about defining a link like this?

`<a href="#"><img data-bind="attr: { src: icon }" /><span data-bind="text: name" /></a>`

Comment: Hah. So simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use knockout's container less syntax to achieve this.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: list">
    <li>
        <a><img data-bind="attr: { src: icon }" />
        <!--ko text: name--><!--/ko-->
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```